# Где проверять склонение слов?

Tags: орфоэпия, лексикография, словари

Подскажите, пожалуйста, словарь где можно увидеть склонение слов и их ударение. Надеюсь, такой вопрос допустим на этом форуме?

Comment: http://gramdict.ru/declension/symbols

Comment: http://dazor.narod.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0115.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для проверки знаний или подтверждения своего мнения я обычно использую несколько общеизвестных источников.

1. Словари, которые представлены на сайте [gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3).
   Очень удобно: и ударение есть, и основные падежи, и толкование.
2. Словари и энциклопедии на Академике ([dic. academic.ru](https://dic.academic.ru/)).
   Здесь можно выбрать любой словарь из списка "Русский язык" или просто ввести нужное слово (оно отобразится во всех имеющихся на сайте словарях).
3. Грамматический словарь [А. А. Зализняка](https://gufo.me/dict/zaliznyak?page=5&letter=%D0%B7#), в котором представлены и ударение, и все формы слова.
   Открытый [морфологический](http://www.morfologija.ru/) словарь (основан на словаре А. А. Зализняка) интересен тем, что в нем обозначены части речи.
   Словарь Зализняка входит в список четырёх словарей, грамматик и справочников, рекомендованных в 2009 году Межведомственной комиссией по русскому языку при Минобрнауки и содержащих нормы современного русского литературного языка.