# Объясните написание НН

Tags: орфография, прилагательные, причастия

> Царапа**нн**ый

Как объяснить написание НН в этом слове? Мне кажется или это действительно сложный случай? По-моему, это слово — отглагольное прилагательное и писать нужно одну Н: *царапанный* обозначает постоянный признак-качество — нам не важно, кто, как и когда царапал, это слово означает «покрытый царапинами». Вдобавок к этому это слово образовано от глагола несовершенного вида, что тоже аргументирует мою версию. Мне действительно слабо понятно, почему это слово считается причастием и почему там пишется НН. Буду признателен, если поможете разобраться!

Comment: http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.34.   Про двойное н

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> По-моему, это слово — отглагольное прилагательное и писать нужно одну
> Н: царапанный обозначает постоянный признак-качество — нам не важно,
> кто, как и когда царапал, это слово означает «покрытый царапинанми»

Долго пыталась себе представить прилагательное царапаный как постоянный признак-качество  "покрытый царапинами" - не смогла, не смогла представить себе предмет, покрытый царапинами, чтобы не спросить "Кто его поцарапал? Когда его поцарапали?" Кто-то же наложил царапины?

Вот рваные джинсы могу - это мода такая - создать вид, будто их порвали, но на самом деле их не рвали, они сразу такие созданы, кошку драную могу - от старости может так выглядеть, не обязательно её драть.

А вот лицо оцарапанное нужно всё-таки оцарапать, бампер - кто-то его оцарапал, как и спина, стена, горло и т.д. И причём напрашиваются причастия с приставкой или зависимыми словами, а без них, по-моему, это просторечия,  литературная форма именно причастие с двумя Н. В словаре Лопатина потому и присутствует причастие царапанный, что оно употребляется с зависимыми словами: не раз царапанный (бампер).

Так что словари правы, я за -НН-

Answer (score 2):

Ответ изменен

**1. Обратимся к словарю**

В орфографическом словаре мы видим: ***царапанный***, также во всех  словарях его называют **причастием**. Простое решение ("гениальное", наверное). В любом случае, статус и форма письма обозначены, но они не соответствуеют правилу Розенталя.

**2. О правиле 4-х признаков при выборе Н и НН**

Это правило формальное, оно помогает быстро (без грамматического анализа)  выбрать Н или НН, но при этом не различает причастия и прилагательные: в причастиях пишется НН, а в прилагательных как Н, так и НН.

Поэтому у этого правила много исключений (например, *слышанный* пишется с двумя НН). В этих случаях  приходится проводить грамматический анализ: определять качественный признак для прилагательного и признак по действию для причастия, учитывать способ образования слова и т.д.

**3. Грамматический анализ**

Итак, мы обращаемся к грамматическому справочнику (например, Грамматика-80) и смотрим раздел: Словообразование прилагательных. Прилагательные, мотивированные глаголами.

И читаем. **Суффикс Н, ЕН:**  значение признака, возникающего как **результат процесса**, когда предмет был объектом этого процесса. Форма ***царапать — царапаный*** подходит под это определение.

Получается, что ***царапаный*** — это отглагольное прилагательное. Известно, что страдательные **причастия** прошедшего времени  образуются только от глаголов **совершенного вида**, а у нас несовершенный вид. Значит,  согласно словарю, прилагательное должно **перейти в причастие и обратно не возвращаться?**

А вот почему именно так, почему не остается парный вариант — это непонятно. Обычно такой переход происходит при наличии **зависимых слов**, хотя возможны и другие случаи. Например, в обособленных оборотах признак проявляется как действие. **Но у нас-то что?**

**4. Обратимся к Нацкорусу:**

Когда Лариса сидела за рулем, она... приговаривала: «Василиса ты моя прекрасная, ты не смотри, что одежка у тебя **царапанная**, зато душа у тебя чистая, мытая-перемытая моющим маслом, карбюратор отрегулирован, компрессия замечательная. [Ю. И. Визбор. Завтрак с видом на Эльбрус (1983)]

Стекла в них были **царапаные** и к тому же чуть искажали, но когда он, поблагодарив караульных, вышел на платформу, то понял, что без них ему было бы не обойтись. [Дмитрий Глуховский. Метро 2033 (2005)]

И если хорошенько рассмотреть вещи в лупу, обычно видишь, что они **совсем не царапанные**, не прошедшие страха тайников сталинской эпохи, просто вышедшие из мастерской, совсем не жившие, без теплоты, свойственной работам этого великого русского ювелирного дома. [А. Васильев.  2006]

Как мы видим, обе формы употребляются.

**5. Специальная лексика**

А бывает так, что поверхность **специально покрывают царапинами**? Оказывается да, продаются металлические листы с такой структурой, и на ценники обозначено: **Царапанный** алюминий анодированный листовой. Иногда встречает и "царапаный", но редко.

То есть в качестве специальной лексики можно было бы писать ***царапаный*** (так же, как *рифленый*), но не принято. Термин встречается редко, поэтому ориентируются на словарную орфографию. Но  значение здесь  именно "в качестве", по смыслу это **прилагательное.**

**6. Вывод**

И какой вывод? Очень простой: пишем ***царапанный***. Мы всегда согласны со словарем. **Нам как скажут, так мы и напишем.**

Comment: 1. _Значит, согласно словарю, прилагательное должно перейти в причастие и обратное не возвращаться?_ Наверно, _обратно_? 2. В орфографическом словаре Лопатина: царапаный, _прил._ (https://gufo.me/dict/orthography_lopatin/%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) Не знаю, правда, можно ли доверять _этому_ словарю (единственному, по-моему, в котором "царапаный" — это прилагательное).

Comment: @Римма Надёжнее доверять словарю Лопатина [на Грамоте](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x).

Comment: Конечно-конечно, я и сама использую словари "Грамоты" (см.: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461439/%d0%93%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2/461448#461448). Я имела в виду, что этот словарь единственный, в котором я обнаружила "царапаный". У меня есть четырехтомный словарь (1958—1961) — в нем слова "царапаный" и "царапанный" отсутствуют.

Comment: @Sharon О-ёй! Кто-то от души минусов понаставил! И опять — без всяких объяснений. Непорядок. P. S. Конечно же, ВЫ _можете_ доверять только себе — ВАШИ знания это позволяют. Мне же, дилетанту, гораздо сложнее — и с выбором источников, и с формулировками... Но поддержка, думаю, нужна всем и всегда.

Comment: Да, минусовали меня действительно от души. Дорогие друзья, так что же неправильно в моем ответе, в каком пункте ошибка? Подскажите, пожалуйста, я исправлю.  Право же, я очень старалась поделиться с вами знаниями и примеры в Нацкорпусе  подходящие нашла. Они вам ни о чем не говорят, ни в чем не убеждают? И если всё правильно, то что тогда? Неужели неприязнь ко мне вам всего дороже - и истины, и любви к родному языку.

Comment: Sharon, скажите, а что, больше было минусов? Сейчас один.

Comment: @Александр, дело в том, что практически одновременно "поотминусовали" **оба** ответа (что странно) — поэтому я и возмущалась. Я поддержала Sharon.

Comment: Я тоже. Сейчас посмотрел на странице Sharon репутацию: там один голос против (-2 балла) и один "отзыв голоса за" (-10 баллов).

Comment: Александр  и Римма спасибо вам за участие,  вы -  та аудитория, которая мне наиболее дорога. Наше голосование во многом субъективно, но иногда эта субъективность просто зашкаливает и ничего, кроме негативного отношения к участнику, уже не выражает. Данный случай яркий  тому  пример. Мой первый ответ, за который проголосовали, меня не очень устроил, показался мне поверхностным . Так бы я ответила раньше, а сейчас работаю по-другому. Во втором варианте я даю полный грамматический анализ двух форм, привожу  реальные текстовые примеры, где они применяются.

Comment: Я полагаю, что лучше  бы оставить обе формы, но  делаю вывод, что нормированной является одна – «царапанный», ей и надо следовать.И получаю в ответ минус 12 баллов:  минусовка, снятое положительное голосование – и никакого при этом обоснования. Неприятно, конечно,  для меня это как эмоциональная пощечина.  Но, вероятно,  это мои трудности: здесь нежелательно расслабляться и всегда ждать доброго  или хотя бы  справедливого в себе отношения.